# standard way to $set a field to "missing" in mongoDB, i.e. $unset it

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```
                  {
                    $set: {
                      cheese: {
                        $cond: [
                          { $eq: [{ $type: "$cheese" }, "missing"] },
                          "$cheese",
                          7,
                        ],
                      },
                    },
                  }
```

If I set a field's value to `undefined`, it will be converted to `null`. That's not the goal. The goal is to remove the field. I cannot use `$unset` because it is conditional.

So the query above does work, i.e. setting the field to another field, via `$a_field_that_does_not_exist`, will remove the field.

However, is this the standard way? Remember, it is conditional, so we cannot use `$unset`. We have to `$set` to field to something, and that something must have the effect of removing the field.

Comment: Have you tried `$$REMOVE`?

Comment: according to documents, $$REMOVE is for projecting stage. will it also work the same in set stage? will check

Comment: Where did you read that? Documentation clearly states *Both stages are equivalent to a $project stage that explicitly specifies all existing fields in the input documents and adds the new fields.*